# What are the initial classes called in university and how do they work?

Tags: novel

So for first year students what would they call the initial courses (prerequisites) they have to take to take to courses they want to take the next semester/year. Is is intro to or 101 or both? How does that work?

Comment: Shea, your question seems to be off-topic for Writers.SE. However, I'm not able to suggest a good SE for your question, because it is probably off-topic also in Academia.SE.

Comment: Since when is any question a writer asks off-topic?

Comment: Ehm... would you ask here, for instance, the recipe of the Cesar salad just because you need to report it in a novel? ;-)

Comment: If I had looked long enough without being able to find an answer and it was relevant, probably. Yahoo answers is useless and this is the fastest way to get answers if you're on a deadline.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about writing, editing, or a related field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any course you have to take in order to take a subsequent course is a *prerequisite*. It doesn't make any difference if you take the initial course your first year, third year, or sixth year. The *pre* part refers to the requirement of taking it before some subsequent course.

An intro course is the first course you take on a topic. This may or may not be numbered 101; that's up to the university. The basic-level composition courses at my university were labeled 050 and 051. And again, the year you take that course is irrelevant.

You could, if you qualified, take all 300-level courses in your first year at school. Don't confuse the amount of time you've been at a school with the content of the courses you're taking.